# nested CASE not working

Tags: sql, case

The below SQL query lets me find the Office 365 update channel. But it does not handle the case when the Registry table has no entry for a computer.
I have tried many different nested CASES, all fail badly. I'm just a novice SQL guy.  Can someone point in the correct direction please?

### good but does not handle if tblRegistry is missing.

```
SELECT
tblAssets.AssetName,
CASE 
    WHEN tblRegistry.Value = 'http://officecdn.microsoft.com/pr/492350f6-3a01-4f97-b9c0-c7c6ddf67d60' THEN 'Monthly' 
    WHEN tblRegistry.Value = 'http://officecdn.microsoft.com/pr/7ffbc6bf-bc32-4f92-8982-f9dd17fd3114' THEN 'Semi-Annual' 
    WHEN tblRegistry.Value = 'http://officecdn.microsoft.com/pr/64256afe-f5d9-4f86-8936-8840a6a4f5be' THEN 'Monthly Targeted' 
    WHEN tblRegistry.Value = 'http://officecdn.microsoft.com/pr/b8f9b850-328d-4355-9145-c59439a0c4cf' THEN 'Semi-Annual Targeted'
    ELSE 'Bad-Registry'+'_'+tblRegistry.Value END AS o365channel
FROM tblAssets
INNER JOIN tblRegistry ON tblRegistry.AssetID = tblAssets.AssetID
WHERE (tblRegistry.Regkey = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration') AND (tblRegistry.Valuename = 'UpdateChannel')
```

### really bad

```
SELECT
tblAssets.AssetName,
CASE WHEN tblAssets.AssetName in 
    (
    select tblAssets.AssetName
    FROM tblAssets
    INNER JOIN tblRegistry ON tblRegistry.AssetID = tblAssets.AssetID
    WHERE (tblRegistry.Regkey = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration') AND (tblRegistry.Valuename = 'UpdateChannel')
    )
    select tblAssets.AssetName,
    CASE
        WHEN tblRegistry.Value = 'http://officecdn.microsoft.com/pr/492350f6-3a01-4f97-b9c0-c7c6ddf67d60' THEN 'Monthly' 
        WHEN tblRegistry.Value = 'http://officecdn.microsoft.com/pr/7ffbc6bf-bc32-4f92-8982-f9dd17fd3114' THEN 'Semi-Annual' 
        WHEN tblRegistry.Value = 'http://officecdn.microsoft.com/pr/64256afe-f5d9-4f86-8936-8840a6a4f5be' THEN 'Monthly Targeted' 
        WHEN tblRegistry.Value = 'http://officecdn.microsoft.com/pr/b8f9b850-328d-4355-9145-c59439a0c4cf' THEN 'Semi-Annual Targeted'
        ELSE 'Bad-RegKey'+'_'+tblRegistry.Value
    END
ELSE 'Bad-RegMissing'
END AS o365channel
FROM tblAssets
```

Thanks in advance,
ccutler

Comment: why don't you start by describing the logic before building the nested condition?

Comment: and which sql version?

Comment: Unrelated, but: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154251/is-adding-the-tbl-prefix-to-table-names-really-a-problem

Comment: Simplify your question. For example have literals 'A', 'B' and 'C', instead of 'http://officecdn.microsoft.com/pr/492350f6-3a01-4f97-b9c0-c7c6ddf67d60', 'http://officecdn.microsoft.com/pr/7ffbc6bf-bc32-4f92-8982-f9dd17fd3114' and 'http://officecdn.microsoft.com/pr/64256afe-f5d9-4f86-8936-8840a6a4f5be'. To make it easier to help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT tblAssets.AssetName,
       CASE 
            WHEN tblRegistry.Value = 'http://officecdn.microsoft.com/pr/492350f6-3a01-4f97-b9c0-c7c6ddf67d60' THEN 'Monthly' 
            WHEN tblRegistry.Value = 'http://officecdn.microsoft.com/pr/7ffbc6bf-bc32-4f92-8982-f9dd17fd3114' THEN 'Semi-Annual' 
            WHEN tblRegistry.Value = 'http://officecdn.microsoft.com/pr/64256afe-f5d9-4f86-8936-8840a6a4f5be' THEN 'Monthly Targeted' 
            WHEN tblRegistry.Value = 'http://officecdn.microsoft.com/pr/b8f9b850-328d-4355-9145-c59439a0c4cf' THEN 'Semi-Annual Targeted'
            ELSE 'Bad-Registry'+'_'+tblRegistry.Value
       END AS o365channel
FROM tblAssets
LEFT JOIN tblRegistry
    ON tblRegistry.AssetID = tblAssets.AssetID
    AND (tblRegistry.Regkey = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration')
    AND (tblRegistry.Valuename = 'UpdateChannel')
```

Comment: Stack Overflow --- your query worked great and taught me something new.

maSTAShuFu  -- Sorry, I should have added more detail instead of going straight to the query.   It was for MS SQL 2012.

note:  this was a vendor supplied database, so I don't control the 'tbl' prefixes
 But I was trying to find the Office365 channel for computers but my query failed on computers whose registry had not been scanned.

Thank you both very much.